# .jsm vs .js files

Tags: javascript

I am creating a javascript module for a firefox extension. I'm curious if the extension makes a difference. In the examples I've seen, it looks like either one is ok and I wanted to make sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No difference at all.

I guess it is just convenient to know which files are "modules" at a glance, but anyway there is no such thing as a formal javascript module, it is all convention.

Comment: This is incorrect as of now (2016).  .jsm is used to denote that it is a javascript module, like in MrHIDEn's answer.  This pertains more to node than to the browser, but .jsm usually means expect `import` and `export` keywords.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski You might be mistaking this with .mjs, which is different from this.

Answer (score 10):

***Attention: My answer looks obsolete nowadays.***

Mozilla defines .jsm here: [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using)
In their definition you must define exported vars and functions,
`var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["foo", "bar"];` Only those will be in the scope.
But I really do not know if this works in HTML pages.

**Edited**
[**(Mirror of)** JavaScript code modules - color](https://www.shuzhiduo.com/A/8Bz8xv9Ozx/)
[**(Mozilla cach of)** JavaScript code modules - old style](https://developer.mozilla.org.cach3.com/en-US/JavaScript_code_modules/Using)
As [@blaedj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050853/blaedj) mentioned below this would be better answer: [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: I think the correct link is now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules, the link in the answer above 404s now. That being said, the link I pasted talks about .mjs files, so it may not be an exact match

Comment: The link that blaedj has provided is to ESM JavaScript modules. For people working on mozilla/gecko code, `.mjs` is mozilla's module system. See the MDN backup for more details: https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using